# What constitutes a "Hesped" (eulogy)?

Tags: halacha-theory, mourning-aveilus, funeral-burial-levaya, simchah-joy-happiness

There are certain dates throughout the year when one may not give a "Hesped" (eulogy) because of a certain level of happiness associated with those dates.

However, I've attended funerals conducted on some of those dates; the bottom line is that, if someone passes away, the body needs to be buried, and the custom, unless it is a day when Melachah (labor) is prohibited, is to have a funeral at which people deliver speeches about the deceased and offer comfort to the family.  I've heard such speeches open with, "We are forbidden from eulogizing today, however I just want to say a few words about..."

So what exactly is not allowed, and how are these speeches not "Hespedim"?

Comment: Many times they just are Hespedim. It's really hard to agree to skip Hespedim at a funeral.

Comment: @DoubleAA, well, if it's Asur...

Comment: I'm not defending the decision, but I think we can all agree such a sin would not be considered _lehach'is_. Do you want to be the one to tell a grieving family member that they can't speak at the funeral?? מוטב שיהיו שוגגין...

Comment: We generally hold that *hesped* involves raising one's voice, and speaking with words of sorrow so as to prompt others to cry over the deceased (Tur, YD 344: "ומצוותו שירים קולו לומר עליו דברים המשברים הלב כדי להרבות בכייה"). This type of eulogy should not be done on the dates in question.

Comment: @Fred That just say one _should_ raise their voice, not that a hesped by definition must include voice raising.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think ומצוותו does in fact indicate a definition.

Comment: @Fred So someone with a cold who has everyone bawling by his speech has failed to fulfill the mitzva??

Comment: @Fred, looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know, perhaps the Tur meant that raising one's voice is a mechanism to fulfill the mitzva of *hesped*, which is fundamentally characterized by giving a sorrowful speech designed to prompt crying (see also *B'rachos* 6b: אמר רב ששת אגרא דהספדא דלויי, and Rashi ad loc.). (Also, see *Y'rushalmi* (*Mo'ed Katan* 3:5): דאמר רבי אבהו (יחזקאל כד) האנק דום מיכן שהוא צריך לצווח. I'm not sure whether this is meant to be synonymous with *hesped*).

Comment: @DoubleAA In fact, there's a *machlokes* whether *tziduk hadin* is considered a form of *hesped* and therefore omitted on days when *hespedim* are prohibited. I guess *tziduk hadin* doesn't necessitate a raised voice, so at least those who prohibit saying it (e.g. the Rama) might hold that a raised voice is not a critical component of a *hesped* (see also Tur YD 401:6).